# Mint 17.3 Wi-Fi does not work after resuming from suspension

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, cinnamon, suspend, hibernate

My Wi-Fi will not work after **suspending** but *WILL* work after **hibernating.**
I've tried a couple things and have had some luck so I'll post what I've done and the effects I've seen.

```
$ sudo lshw

    description: Notebook
    product: HP ENVY 14 Notebook PC (J9L59UA#ABA)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: 096C120014405F10000620182
    serial: 5CD5143D9B
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5335KV G=N L=CON B=HP S=ENV X=Null sku=J9L59UA#ABA uuid=35434435-3134-3344-3942-D0BF9C9A90FA
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 2298
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: 78.21
       serial: PEWNT018J8I1ER
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde
          physical id: 0
          version: F.36
          date: 02/02/2015
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6080KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2200MHz
          capacity: 2700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap xsaveopt cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 15
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 12GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: HMT451S6AFR8A-PB
             vendor: Hynix
             physical id: 0
             serial: 16575711
             slot: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M471B1G73QH0-YK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 25172419
             slot: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:c1000000-c1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Broadwell-U Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:53 memory:c3210000-c3213fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:c3200000-c320ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:49 memory:c321a000-c321a01f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:52 memory:c3214000-c3217fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:43 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:c2000000-c2ffffff ioport:c0000000(size=16777216)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:44 memory:c3100000-c31fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 3160
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 83
                serial: 34:e6:ad:0c:bf:e3
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-32-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 ip=192.168.1.184 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:51 memory:c3100000-c3101fff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e3
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:45 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:c3000000-c30fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: d0:bf:9c:9a:90:fa
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:48 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3004000-c3004fff memory:c3000000-c3003fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:47 ioport:5088(size=8) ioport:5094(size=4) ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5090(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:c3218000-c32187ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:c3219000-c32190ff ioport:5040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1
             vendor: Toshiba
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 2C
             serial: 25L4PCC6T
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=92d26b47-bd01-4c24-968c-fb866690e33a sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: fcda-a86a
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EFI partition
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot
                version: 1.0
                serial: 111b5642-8767-4f0b-b5f7-bec74f8f942f
                size: 244MiB
                capabilities: extended_attributes ext2 initialized
                configuration: filesystem=ext2 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2016-05-25 18:36:22 mount.fstype=ext2 mount.options=rw,relatime,stripe=4 mounted=2016-05-25 18:36:22 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: EFI partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: 2af1feb6-4486-442a-a440-248d3f612d38
                size: 930GiB
                capacity: 930GiB
                width: 512 bits
                capabilities: encrypted luks initialized
                configuration: bits=512 cipher=aes filesystem=luks hash=sha1 mode=xts-plain64 version=1
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRW  DU8A6SH
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: DH61
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-battery
       product: VI04041
       vendor: 13-54
       physical id: 1
       version: ManufDate
       serial: DummySerialNumber
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 41440mWh
       configuration: voltage=14.8V
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
```

I ran `nmcli nm` after suspending and got

```
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE        
running         disconnected    disabled        disabled   enabled
```

This output is different than most threads I've seen so that is why I'm making a new post.

`lshw -C network` shows:

```
    *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 83
       serial: 34:e6:ad:0c:bf:e3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-32-generic firmware=25.17.12.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:53 memory:c3100000-c3101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: d0:bf:9c:9a:90:fa
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3004000-c3004fff memory:c3000000-c3003fff
```

#### Attempted fix(s)

1. I tried

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
   ```

   and put in:

   ```
   SUSPEND_MODULES="iwlwifi"
   ```

   I also tried to put in:

   ```
   SUSPEND_MODULES="r8169"
   ```

   out of desperation.

   Both of these did nothing...
2. I tried:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_resume_wifi
   ```

   and put in:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   case $1 in

   suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
       sudo nmcli n off
       ;;
       resume|thaw)
           sudo nmcli n on
       ;;
   esac
   ```

   This made my Wi-Fi work, but took away my ability to suspend or hibernate. Closing my lid would simply log me out and turn of my screen, nothing more...

Help would be most certainly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html) you need to edit `/etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules` configuration file by adding the following line :

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES <kernel_module_used_by_the_interface>"
```

In your case the kernel module in use is `iwlwifi` :

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="$SUSPEND_MODULES iwlwifi"
```

then edit your `10_resume_wifi` like the following example:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "${1}" in
  resume|thaw)
    nmcli r wifi off && nmcli r wifi on;
esac
```